# database/algorithm for a rate structure

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have to calculate a price based on a rate structure along these lines:

```
$303.00 fixed price up to 500 units
$0.023 additional per unit from 501-10,000 units
$0.022 additional per unit from 10,001-25,000 units
$0.021 additional per unit from 25,001-50,000 units
```

I'm a little lost on setting up a database structure and algorithm (the larger sticking point) for calculating this. Has anyone done this? Is there a nice, elegant way of calculating this sort of thing?

**edit:**  As an example, a 25,100 unit run would cost $303.00 for the first 500 units, $218.50 for the next 9,500 units, $330.00 for the next 15,000 units, and $2.10 for the next 100 units, for a total of $853.60.

It *wouldn't* be a simple 25,100 * $0.021 calculation - I'm well aware of how to select and calculate that.

Similar to the way income tax is assessed - on a marginal basis.

Comment: No, it's for an internal system at work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I wound up doing:

```
size  units     fixed     per
1       500   303.000   0.000
1     10000     0.000   0.023
1     25000     0.000   0.022
1     50000     0.000   0.021



function calculate_price($size, $quantity) {
  global $db;

  $price = 0;
  $count = 0;

  // fetch rates from the database
  // note: $size is already sanitised by the calling function
  $query = "SELECT units, flat, per FROM rates WHERE size={$size} ORDER BY units ASC";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  // step through the rates
  while($rate = $result->fetch_object()) {
    // figure out how many of our units fall within this tier
    $tier_count = max(0, min($quantity - $count, $rate->units - $count));

    // calculate the price for this tier, including any flat rate
    $tier_price = $rate->flat + ($rate->per * $tier_count);

    // add tier price and count to the totals
    $price += $tier_price;
    $count += $tier_count;

    // store the last, largest number of units rate for any leftovers outside our tiers
    $last_rate = $rate;
  }

  // if some of our units fall outside our defined tiers, use the last tier's values for them
  if($count < $quantity) {
    $tier_count = $quantity - $count;
    $tier_price = $last_rate->flat + ($last_rate->per * $tier_count);
    $price += $tier_price;
    $count += $tier_count;
  }

  return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Python

```
from collections import namedtuple

RateRule= namedtuple( 'RateRule', ['qty_band','fixed','per_unit'] )    

rate_table = [
    RateRule(500, 303, None),
    RateRule(9500, None, 0.023),
    RateRule(15000, None, 0.022),
    RateRule(25000, None, 0.021)
]

def total_price( units, rate_table ):
    # Base
    total = rate_table[0].fixed
    units_purchased_so_far = rate_table[0].qty_band
    # Whole Price Bands
    rule = 1
    while units > units_purchased_so_far + rate_table[rule].qty_band:
        total += rate_table[rule].qty_band * rate_table[rule].per_unit
        units_purchased_so_far += rate_table[rule].qty_band
        rule += 1
    # Units within the top Price Band
    if units > units_purchased_so_far:
        total += (units - units_purchased_so_far) * rate_table[rule].per_unit
    return total
```

Comment: It's the marginal calculation that's throwing me for a loop. I can't just do something that simple. As an example, a 25,100 unit run would cost $303.00 for the first 500 units, $218.50 for the next 9,500 units, $330.00 for the next 15,000 units, and $2.10 for the next 100 units.

Comment: That's not quite clear from your original question and not the 'normal' way quantity discounts are calculated. Yours are still in different bands.

Comment: You didn't say that, I too thought it was $0.022 for *every* unit if the order was over 10k.  I'll give you a hint, though:  the first 10k will always cost the same price, whether they order 10,001 or 100,000 units.

Comment: Also, please don't give every single answer -1 simply because your question was unclear, that is just bad manners.

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks for the edit, but this answer still does not account for the marginal rate structure. I'd need to calculate the units beyond each price stepping point, and I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way than brute force.

Comment: @BlueRaja Having updated the question to be more clear, the answers assuming I was looking for a simple single-price rate are no longer "useful" to the question, as indicated by the tooltip.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want something flexible, otherwise it would be trivial to hardcode it.

You could use a pricing table:

```
ID MAX    FIX    UNIT
1  500    303    0
2  9500   0      .23
3  15000  0      .22
4  25000  0      .21
```

Then you could calculate as follows:

```
$items = ?;
$cost = 0;
$rows = get_rows("select max, fix, unit from pricing order by id asc");
foreach ($rows as $r)
{
    if ($items <= 0)
        break;
    $cost += $r['fix'] + min($r['max'], $items) * $r['unit'];
    $items -= $r['max'];
}
```

I have assumed that you want the algorithm in PHP.

Comment: I hadn't thought about expressing the number of units in "number since last price point" instead of "number since 0". Will give this a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Product
-------
[PK] ProductID


Price
-----
[PK] PriceID
[FK] ProductID
Price
QtyMin
QtyMax
```

So effectively a 1-many relationship between product and price. You could use a sentinel value for the maximum if you require a flat rate regardless of quantity.

Comment: That doesn't account for having both fixed and per-unit price, and it's more the calculation from the database results that I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 CASE is_fixed_price
  WHEN 1
   THEN unit_price / ?  
  ELSE
   unit_price
  END
FROM rate_structure
WHERE ? BETWEEN min_qty AND max_qty
```

Where ? is the quantity your customer wants to order. Syntax off the top of my head, for mysql 5.x. The side effect of this is potential rounding error accumulation.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something in the syntax here, this appears to do a non-marginal calculation at a single price point.

Comment: Oh, my bad; the marginal cost as you specified doesn't make sense to me - typically (in the context of a single abstract business) unit cost goes down and not up when the quantity is increased. I thought that in your scenario, minimal payment is $300 whether you order 1 unit or 500. It is not and my code is incorrect. However, you can still use the conditionals as I showed you to do the calculations as you want them.